# NASM, how to write straight to the hard disk and read from it in Real Mode

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-system, bootloader, hard-drive

On the latest version of Ubuntu, x64.

I am essentially wondering how operating systems are able to install themselves on computers when booted from flash drives, but I would like to do this in Real Mode and not Protected or Long Mode. Surely older operating systems like MS-DOS used to do this.

For Real Mode, is there an interrupt for this? Or do I need to switch to Protected or Long Mode first before I am able to write data straight to the hard disk and/or read from that same area?

Doing this for a small Real Mode OS that has a 2-stage bootloader:

```
org 0x7C00
mov ah, 0
int 13h
mov dx, 0
mov ah, 2
mov al, 10h
mov dl, 0x80
mov ch, 0
mov dh, 0
mov cl, 2
mov bx, stage2
int 0x13
jmp stage2
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55

msg db "!!"

%include "read.s" ;read.s does not exist yet, as I do not know how to read from an address on the hard disk
%include "write.s" ;write.s does not exist yet, as I do not know how to write to an address on the hard disk

stage2:
    call ReadStr ;always reads from the same address, if the message is there, sets bl to 0x01. Otherwise, sets bl to 0x00.
    cmp bl, 0x00
    je load
    mov ah, 0eh
    mov al, "#" ;tiny message to tell me that the string is already at the address
    mov bx, 0
    int 10h
    jmp $
load:
    mov ax, [msg]
    call LoadStr ;loads the message to the same address that ReadStr reads from
    mov ah, 0eh
    mov al, "$" ;tiny message to tell me that the string does not already exist at the address
    mov bx, 0
    int 10h
    jmp $
```

The idea here is that the first time I boot the bootloader, it should print '$', but the second time I boot it, it should print '#' as the data already exists on the hard disk at the specific address. But I don't know how to implement read.s and write.s. Ideally (the main objective of this), the OS will install itself on the computer the first time I boot up the bootloader on a flash drive. Do I need to first set Long Mode to do this, or is it possible in BIOS?

Comment: If accessing hard drives from real mode look at extended disk read [int 13h/ah=42h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0708.htm) and extended disk write [int 13h/ah=43h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0710.htm). A list of the BIOS interrupts related to diska ccess can be found here: http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-13.htm. If your BIOS is set to boot a USB HDD (and not USB FDD) it should act like a Hard Drive for your purposes.

Comment: so for int 13h/ah=43h (extended write), the drive number (dl), should I set this to 0x80 because I am writing to the hard disk?

Comment: When the BIOS transfers control to your bootloader (that is read  from the first sector) it sets _DL_ to the drive number of the device being booted. you should use that value for disk reads and writes to the media that booted.

Comment: Does the transfer buffer in the data address packet contain the string? Maybe a code example might help

Comment: You don't read strings per se. You read sector(s) of data at a time. It may contain strings or binary data etc. The read routine reads a specified number of sectors into memory. You have to interpret that data whichever way you see fit.

Comment: Is there a significant difference between extended read/write and regular read/write?

Comment: Extended disk reads are meant for higher capacity media (Hard Drives, Flash, CD-ROM). Regular disk reads use to have size limitations (restrictions because of how cylinder-head-secttor addressing was implemented) without specialized special BIOS translation. With regular reads and rites you may only be able to see part of the media. These days regular disk read/writes are pretty much used for floppy drive media.Floppy drive (or floppy drive emulated devices). Extended disk reads/writes usually aren't supported on floppy drives.

Comment: This is in response to a now deleted comment: That's a more difficult question because it is dependent on what file system is being used.A proper file system is used to lookup what places on the media files are stored.You don't have to use a file system and can use specialized tools (like `dd` on Linux) to write data to specific sectors on the drive. Your code can then read those specific sectors to retrieve the information.

Comment: Partition Type for the partition on my flash drive that contains the code says "W95 FAT32 (LBA) (Bootable)" btw. Is there an interrupt for locating sectors on the flash drive itself to write to? For example, if I wanted to overwrite sector 1 on the flash drive (512 bytes) with whatever is on sector 2 (also 512 bytes), would I use an extended write to do that?

Comment: You can use extended disk reads and writes to copy data from one sector to another - yes. Assuming of course the media isn't write protected.

Comment: Okay, because the main problem that I keep running into is that I don't know where the source and destination sector addresses would go in the disk address packet. I'm so used to using int 13h/ah=2 to read 1 sector into another and overwrite a sector this way, but the problem with this is that doesn't seem to actually change the data on the flash drive itself; the only thing that seems to change with that is some sort of runtime stack frame or something that shows up when the bootloader is loaded up, because if I boot the flash drive twice, it does the exact same thing, and it doesn't seem to

Comment: show any differences (overwriting 1 sector with another sector) when I boot the flash drive again.

Comment: With CHS (regular disk reads/writes) sector numbers start at 1. With etended disk reads/writes LBA (sector number) is 0 based.

Comment: https://wiki.osdev.org/ATA_in_x86_RealMode_(BIOS)#x86_Examples Found this page on reading from the LBA, with the part `d_lba: dd 1`, this would read from the second sector. Does this entire code read from the second sector into the first sector, as 0x7C00 is used for the "memory buffer destination address"?

Comment: Additionally (sorry I have so many questions, I'm still new to assembly), for regular read/write, what are the cylinder and head number?

Comment: I would suggest learning assembly by not doing bootloaders. Find tasks that are more trivial. The problem with bootloaders and drives is that you have to have a solid understanding of the methods to access them. Extended disk reads are easier since sector number go from 0 to the maximum number of sectors on the device. CHS (Cylinder Head Sectors) addressing is more complex. You can search Google for info on it. A good staris:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder-head-sector . That is just a starting point.

Comment: not sure how i'll learn how to do something by not working on it :P. This is actually one of the last things I need to learn how to do in order to legitimately start working on the small Real Mode OS. This is part of the learning process, as I plan on learning how to enter protected/long mode after the Real Mode OS is done. I am trying to learn assembly through the most natural use of it AKA flat assembly, not through abstractions like elf64 assembly. If I learn from an os-specific assembly, I'll also learn abstractions that will make it harder for me to understand raw OS development.

Comment: It's like learning java for the first time, and then switching over to the language that you wanted to learn in the first place, C, and wondering where the heck the arraylists and such went and then having to learn an entirely new world of thought. I am trying to avoid this.

Comment: You'll have to learn how to read more technical information on the internet. Sometimes conflicting. There are good and bad tutorials (almost all the codeproject tutorials using real mode for OSDev are uttercrap for example). [OSDev Wiki](https://wiki.osdev.org/Expanded_Main_Page) has a lot of information. Some of it is related to Real Mode (although much of it is devoted to protected mode and long mode). There is a section onreal mode disk access: https://wiki.osdev.org/ATA_in_x86_RealMode_(BIOS)

Comment: Got the extended read working! It takes sector 2 and moves it to sector 1. Now the only thing left is to find out how to permanently move it to sector 1, so that even if I reboot the flash drive, sector 2 stays copied to sector 1. This is the part that I haven't figured out how to do yet

Answer (score 1):

Got something working; the first time it is booted it will print "!#" but every time after that when it boots up, it will print "##" because the flash drive's second sector has been overwritten by the flash drive's third sector. Only thing this is missing is how to do this with the hard drive instead of the flash drive, but at least I now know how to rewrite the flash drive, and thus can simulate memory storage in some way, even if in an inefficient way. Next step is to find out how to inject a bootable sector into the actual computer's memory so that I can use the raw power of RAM to store and manipulate data.

```
org 0x7C00
stage1:
    mov ah, 2
    mov cl, 2
    mov bx, stage2
    int 13h

    call stage2

    mov ah, 2
    mov cl, 3
    mov bx, stage2
    int 13h

    mov ah, 3
    mov cl, 2
    mov bx, stage2
    int 13h

    mov ah, 2
    mov cl, 2
    mov bx, stage2
    int 13h

    call stage2

    jmp $

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
stage2:
    mov ah, 0eh
    mov al, "!"
    mov bx, 0
    int 10h
    ret
times 1024-($-$$) db 0
stage3:
    mov ah, 0eh
    mov al, "#"
    mov bx, 0
    int 10h
    ret
times 1536-($-$$) db 0
```

Answer (score 0):

your answer is on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_13H, you should change dl to number of driver and then operations occur on that driver:

```
mov dl,[that_driver_number]
```

notice: when bios want's to run bootloader sets dl to bootloader driver (for example if bootloader on cd driver 1, it sets to E0) also when you didn't change that, your operations occur on your boot program
for example this code should copy your bootloader on hard drive